# Swagger - How to nest a dynamic object inside a response

Tags: swagger, openapi

In the application I am documenting all the HTTP responses are the same:

```json
{
    "status": 200,
    "error": "",
    "data": {}
}
```

So I know I could do something like this:

```
paths:
  /users/{id}:
    get:
      summary: Gets a user by ID.
      response:
        '200':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Unauthorized'
components:
  responses:
    Successfull:
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/SuccessfulResponse'
  schemas:
    # Schema for error response body
    SuccessfulResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        status:
          type: integer
        error:
          type: string
          example: Invalid credentials
        data:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
```

How could I do if I want data to be another object, do I have to create different object for any data object type or can I referenciate the nested data object in some way (inside the path)? In this example data could be a User schema, moreover we could do a Car schema, or whatever. The point is, can I, in the path, set the 200 response as an object and the nested object?

I have been searching in the docs and google about dynamic nested object, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Several things are severely wrong with how you handle errors. Code "200" should not be used for "Unauthorized" (correct code is 401). Attribute "status" makes no sense because that comes with the HTTP protocol itself. So it's either redundant or inconsistent. And "SuccessfulResponse" has attribute "error", this is at least confusing.

Comment: It seems I have missed my explanation, I am not using 200 as the code for everything, that changes for each request. I know this is a mess, and should be improved in the next versión, but I am asking about the nested object and not about if the structure on the API I am documenting is ok. I am glad gor your helo, now can you give me help about my question? @observer

Comment: "In this example data could be a User schema, moreover we could do a Car schema, or whatever" --> and how do you expect a client to parse and make sense of your "data" attribute? Through OpenAPI polymorphism? (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism) Can work from technical point of view, but you should better fix the root problem of the messy API structure. You might be interested in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807